# Can Dominated person/creature which receive no command remember they are being dominated?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, mind-control

This is similar to [Do you remember what happened during Dominate Person?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/do-you-remember-what-happened-during-dominate-person) (Pathfinder, not D&D 5e), but the difference is [I'm not issuing any order to target](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101063/can-i-choose-not-to-control-a-dominated-person).

Will the target remember that they were dominated?

Comment: There's also a difference in that the linked question is about a different game, so the answer might not be the same in yours.

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76729/do-charmed-people-realise-they-were-charmed-after-the-end-of-the-spel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHB p 204

> Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature 
>   might not know it was targeted by a spell at all. An effect 
>   like crackling lightning is obvious, but a more subtle 
>   effect, such as an attempt to read a creature’s thoughts, 
>   typically goes unnoticed, unless a spell says otherwise.

Dominate Person does not “say otherwise” so, irrespective of if you issue commands or not the creature doesn’t necessarily know it is (or was) dominated. Compare this with Friends where the creature knows it was affected after the spell expires - Dominate Person has no equivalent language.

An intelligent creature may be able to guess why it is behaving strangely but it wouldn’t know for sure.